# access the .json file in a folder. i have tried a lot of way. but it all get error

Tags: python, game-development

I am making a simple game that can run through the Terminal (PYTHON)
I am coding it in Linux Ubuntu
it was so easy to access the `.json` file. and everything seem to go really well.

There will be a lot of monster in the game so I make a folder `MobData` in the same folder as the `main.py`

the problem occurred inside "class Mob:"

Here is my code and screenshots of folder
[image: $HOME/scripts]
and
[image: $HOME/scripts/MobData]

```
import json
import random
import os
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

thisFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
cwd = os.getcwd()

def clear():
    os.system("clear")

#first scene. asking for data choice.
clear()
print("---SIMPLE GAME---\n\n\t1.Newgame\n\t2.Continue")

#1.start with new data 2.continue with current data
UserInput = int(input("Player: "))
match UserInput:
    case 1:
        UserInput = int(input("Are you sure? 1.yes 2.no ")) #make sure about consideraion
        match UserInput:
            case 1:
                clear()
                print("---Newgame---")
                PlayerName = str(input("Player's Name (atleast 3 digit. if less than that, set to John): "))
                with open('default.json') as json_file: #take the default data
                    Default = json.load(json_file)
                    json_file.close()
                if len(PlayerName) >= 3: #if the given name is shorter than 3 characters, set the name to default
                    Default["PlayerName"] = PlayerName
                with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file: #set the data to default
                    json.dump(Default, json_file, indent=4)
                    json_file.close()
            case _:
                clear()
                exit()
    case 2:
        clear()
        print("---Continue---")
    case _:
        clear()
        print("---Closed---")
        exit()

#show player infomation
clear()
with open('data.json') as json_file:
    Data = json.load(json_file)
    json_file.close

class Mob:
    def __init__(self, Name):
        fileName = Name+(".json")
        fileDest = cwd+"/"+fileName
        with open(fileDest) as json_file:
            mobData = json.load(json_file)
            json_file.close()
        self.Name = Name
        self.HP = mobData[Health]
        self.BATK = mobData[BaseATK]
        self.BEXP = mobData[BaseEXP]
        self.Loot = mobData[Loot]

    def showInfo(self):
        print(Back.RED + Fore.WHITE + ">> % <<" %(self.Name))

def showPlayerInfo():
    print(Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + ">>> %s <<<" % (Data["PlayerName"]))
    print("Level: ", Data["Level"])
    print("Exp: ", Data["Exp"], "/", Data["CurrentMaxExp"])
    print(Back.GREEN + "HP: ", Data["HealthPoint"])
    print(Back.BLUE + "Energy: ", Data["Energy"])
    print(Back.YELLOW + "Hunger: ", Data["Hunger"])
    print(Back.WHITE + "Coins: ", Data["Coins"])
    print("Status: ", Data["Attributes"])
    print(Back.RED + Fore.WHITE + "Weapon: ", Data["Weapon"])
    print(Fore.RESET + Back.RESET)

def showInventory():
    print(Back.LIGHTYELLOW_EX + Fore.BLACK + "Inventory")
    print(Data["Inventory"])
    print(Fore.RESET + Back.RESET)

def updatePlayerLevel():
    cme = Data["CurrentMaxExp"]
    ce = Data["Exp"]
    level = Data["Level"]
    cme = 100+((level-1)*20)
    if ce >= cme:
        ce-=cme
        level+=1

def showCurrentPlace():
    print(Back.LIGHTRED_EX + Fore.BLACK + "You are at: ", Data["CurrentPlace"])
    print("You can go: ")

showPlayerInfo()
showInventory()
Bat = Mob("bat")
Bat.showInfo()
```

I tried to reach the files

`open("/MobData/bat.json")` <----doesn't work

`open("full destination")` <----doesn't work either

all give an error such as `no such a file or destination`

I'm totally stuck now.

(any tips for my project? it's my first time making something this big.)

Comment: `"/MobData/bat.json"` is an absolute path, maybe `"./MobData/bat.json"`?

Comment: it's not working. i don't know why

Comment: i dont know what that means. but to be sure. the problem is at the "class Mob" sorry that i have not give more source

Comment: Before trying to open the file during Mob.__init__ add *print(fileDest)* This will tell you the name and location of the file you're trying to open

Comment: You will need to show the actual traceback and error you're getting, not "all give an error such as...".

Comment: Print `fileDest`, as you have it right now, even if you get it to work if might not work in someone else's machine. You have `thisFileDir` so why not use that as a base path and work from there to the other files?

Comment: @AKX sorry about that.

Comment: @AKX Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/megaboom642/scripts/main.py", line 99, in <module>
    Bat = Mob("bat")
  File "/home/megaboom642/scripts/main.py", line 54, in __init__
    fileDest = cwd+"/"+fileDest
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fileDest' referenced before assignment     i will put this in my post later

Comment: That line doesn't exist in the code shown

Comment: @Daviid still not working

Comment: @LeoLeo the problem is not that it can't find the file

"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fileDest' referenced before assignment" it's an entirely different problem that you may want to google (you just need to put the variable in another place, or assign something to the variable when you declare it

Comment: @LeoLeo update your code in the question, I'm not scouring comments to piece together your current code and error.

Comment: @Daviid i think i found the right answer now but i will make it all again from zero. i dont know what do you mean by that. update? i dont know which way to update it. cuz i will put it all in a trash. and make a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very stripped-down version of the parts you're having trouble with, with additional logging and error handling. I'm using `pathlib.Path` for file management for convenience here.

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

mobs_directory = Path("./mobs").resolve()
print("Looking for mobs in", mobs_directory)
if not mobs_directory.is_dir():
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"mobs directory {mobs_directory!r} not found")


class Mob:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        data = json.loads((mobs_directory / f"{name}.json").read_text())
        self.HP = data["Health"]
        self.BATK = data["BaseATK"]
        self.BEXP = data["BaseEXP"]
        self.Loot = data["Loot"]

    def describe(self):
        print(
            f"{self.name} has {self.HP} HP, "
            f"{self.BATK} BaseATK, {self.BEXP} BaseEXP, "
            f"and drops {self.Loot}"
        )


Bat = Mob("bat")
Bat.describe()
```

Now, if with a file called `mobs/bat.json` in place next to the program:

```
{
  "Health": 123,
  "BaseATK": 123,
  "BaseEXP": 456,
  "Loot": "absolutely"
}
```

and I run the program, I get:

```
$ python so77344720.py
Looking for mobs in /Users/akx/build/so-misc/mobs
bat has 123 HP, 123 BaseATK, 456 BaseEXP, and drops absolutely
```

Now, `mobs_directory` is relative to the current working directory (`./`), not the program's directory.

If you want to make it always relative to the program's directory, you could do e.g.

```
program_directory = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
mobs_directory = program_directory / "mobs"
```

Comment: look like i have to remake my project. it all looks messy. it's not working yet in my code. but your answer is right. Thanks